# Do I need Identity server od openiddict for Microservices

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a Blazor application that will connect to web api built sa microservices.
I am planning to use jwt for authentication AND authorization needs.
How do I authenticate and authorize jwt Tokens on my Microservices?
Do I need an Identity server or openiddict or could I use asp.net 7 Identity only?
I am planning to use claims for authorization.
i.e. How do service A or service B know if a token it got sa bearer in a web request, is valid without using Identity server or openiddict?
The authentication will be a plain username/password.
I would prefer if I don’t need Identityserver or openiddict at all.

Comment: You'll need a place that is responsible for verifying username and password and then issue your jwt tokens. You can build your own server and the mentioned libs are made to support you in building such a server or you could use an external auth provider, e.g. if you allow login with Google / Microsoft AD / ... only, you'll need no auth server. Your services will know if a token is valid by using information provided by the auth server (see e.g. oidc code flow). If you want your own authentication server, then you should use one of the libs.

Comment: Yes I want to build my own authentication server. I was thinking that the asp.net identity is enough for this. I already have user/password verification and JWTs token generation built. I only need the way of verifying tokens on the Microservices.

Comment: Ok, let's say I go for OpenIdDict. Do I need introspection endpoint? Or can I validate somehow tokens at the resource server (Microservices) themselfs?

Comment: @Luka Usually you should have an `AuthService` that is your primary source of truth for these things. Meaning, you should only validate once and then assume that flow further into the services is using a valid token. This is often done using a Gateway API - where the gateway calls `AuthService` to authenticate and authorize, then the authenticated `User` along with its `Permissions`  is propagated deeper to other services through a header, request body, session data etc.